# How to export dump on old oracle 9.2.0.0.1?

Tags: oracle, export

I have oracle 9.2.0.0.1 version installed . Can i use expdp to export particular dump . If not possible how to use exp on same version ?

Comment: `expdp` (datapump) isn't available until 10g. The [documentation for the 9i utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652.pdf), including `exp`, is still available.

Comment: @AlexPoole How can we use exp command to export complete databse. Let say name of database is ABC

Comment: Can we import dump exported on 9.2.0.0.1 on oracle 11 g ?

Comment: [Any export dump file can be imported into a later release of the Oracle database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL103). So yes, as long as you use the 11g `imp` utility. You probably want to be exporting/importing specific schema though, not the whole database.